# MongoDB Java driver 3.5 support for reference fields in POJOs

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

In the mongodb java driver 3.5 release, "official support" for [POJO mapping was added](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/bson/pojos/).

But it doesn't seem to mention anything about mapping a class to specific collection or storing a pojo field of a class in a separate collection instead of embedding it.

Given:

```
public class Address {
    public ObjectId id;
    public String zipcode;
}

//elsewhere
public class Person {
    public ObjectId id;
    public Address address;
}
```

How do you make it so that inserting a `Person` instance actually inserts something like `{id={some oid}, address={oid1}}` in `people` collection, and `{id={oid1}, zip={some zipcode}}` in `addresses` collection

Will that be coming in a later release or did I just miss some annotation or config step?